# Is it possible to load Javascript and HTML separately in Android WebView with loadData()?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I want to load Javascript and HTML separately in WebView. Basically, I want to have a common Javascript running for any HTML page which will be loaded.

Comment: why you not just load the same `js` file in different `html` files?

Comment: So, I want to have a common javascript and HTML page which is going to be loaded is not under my control. User can make its own HTML.

Comment: the question does not indicate that requirement - while web-development without `F12` tools might be a painful process... however, one can insert as `javascript:...` URL, while using self-invocation pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.

You can have separate Javascript and then evaluate that Javascript using WebView.evaluateJavascript() in onPageFinished() of WebViewClient.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + readInputStream("javascript.js"), null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
/** returns a self-invoking JS function */
protected String getJavaScript(int sequence, String message) {
    return "(function(){" +
       ...
    "})();";
}

/** Script Execution Wrapper */
protected void evalScript(WebView webview, String script) {
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:" + script);
}
```

source: my [GitHub](https://github.com/syslogic/android-sqlite-demo/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/syslogic/sqlite/activity/MainActivity.java#L159).